# Need help iterating over an array In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently struggling with the following problem:

1. Create an `<a>` element,
2. On the new element add an href attribute and its value set to the href property of the "link" object. edit: adding this.. Set the new element's content to the value of the textproperty of the "link" object.
3. Append the new element to the "topMenu" element.
   goal i want to achieve : making 'About' 'Catalog' 'Orders' 'account' into links. (im new to javascript)

Here my code:

```js
var menuLinks = [{
    text: 'about',
    href: '/about'
  },
  {
    text: 'catalog',
    href: '/catalog'
  },
  {
    text: 'orders',
    href: '/orders'
  },
  {
    text: 'account',
    href: '/account'
  },
];

 var links = document.createElement('a');
menuLinks.map(function(links) {
      return '<li>' + links + '</li>';
      document.getElementById("mylinks").href = "menuLinks";
```

Comment: What exactly do you wish to achieve? what is links? we don't know what that looks like and the end result should be what exactly? your question is very confusing

Comment: Array.map does not change the original array, it returns a new array, maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```js
  var menuLinks = [{
    text: 'about',
    href: '/about'
  },
  {
    text: 'catalog',
    href: '/catalog'
  },
  {
    text: 'orders',
    href: '/orders'
  },
  {
    text: 'account',
    href: '/account'
  },
];

let menuAnch=menuLinks.map(r=>`<li> <a href='${r.href}'>${r.text} </a> </li>`).join("");
document.getElementById("mylinks").innerHTML=menuAnch;
console.log(menuAnch);
```

```html
<div id="mylinks"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this:

```js
var menuLinks = [{
    text: 'about',
    href: '/about'
  },
  {
    text: 'catalog',
    href: '/catalog'
  },
  {
    text: 'orders',
    href: '/orders'
  },
  {
    text: 'account',
    href: '/account'
  },
];

var links = menuLinks.map(link => `<a href='${link.href}'>${link.text}</a>`);

console.log(links);
```

Resulting array:

```
[
  "<a href='/about'>about</a>",
  "<a href='/catalog'>catalog</a>",
  "<a href='/orders'>orders</a>",
  "<a href='/account'>account</a>"
]
```